# Mediastore duration of MKV file returns 0

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, mediastore, mkv

I am trying to fetch the duration of MKV file from mediastore . However, it returns me 0. If I use Mediaplayer `MediaPlayer.create` , media player is null and I get a error (-1,2147483648) with a message that prepare failed. I am able to fetch duration of other videos with extension mp4 .Something wrong with the path? Can anyone help?

1st method:

`long duration = cursor.getLong(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DURATION);`

This returns 0.

2nd method:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filePath)); 
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(TestApplication.getAppContext(), uri);
```

`// uri is file:///storage/emulated/0/Movies/Test.MKV`

This returns mp = null.

I also tried `MediaMetadataRetriever` but that also returned null. How can I get the duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the MKV file was corrupted. Hence, closing this.